# Why is session variable is not set or lost?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, session

I have a login page. I input username and password and submited my page via ajax.

In check.php the values from index.php are verified.

And I try to set a SESSION['email'] variable in check.php, but it is not accessible in HOME.php after successfully login to the site.

```html
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function output(x) {
    x=x.trim();
    if(x=="YES") {
        $(location).attr("href","HOME.php");
    } else {
        alert("login failed");
    }
}
 
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
  
        var Username = $("#txtUserName").val();
        var Password = $("#txtPssword").val();
  
        var dataString = 'Username='+ Username+'&Password='+Password;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Check.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response){
                output(response); 
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="post" name="login" id="form">
        Username <input type="email"  id ="txtUserName"  />
        Password <input type="password" id="txtPssword" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
//Check.php

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $email = $_POST['Username'];
        $password = $_POST['Password'];
        if(('ADMIN'==$email)&&('PASS'==$password)) {    
            $_SESSION['email']=$email; // email id stored in a session variable 
            echo "YES";
        } else {
            echo "NO";
        }
    }

?>
```

```php
//HOME.php

<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['email']; // Here session values is losted.
?>
```

Comment: Can you post code for HOME.php.

Comment: in `HOME.php` also add `session_start();` on top just after `<?php` tag

Comment: Did you put `session_start();` at the top of home.php?

Comment: ---------
HOME.php
---------
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $SESSION['email']; // Here session values is losted.
?>

Comment: change $SESSION['email']; to $_SESSION['email'];

Comment: i changed but not work

Comment: Can  you format your code a bit? This is hard to read with all the extra whitespace

Answer (score 7):

You have a syntax error, change `$SESSION['email'];` to `$_SESSION['email'];`

And add a `session_start();` in all of your php page when you need to access to variable session.

Comment: I changed $SESSION['email']; to $_SESSION['email']; but still I cant get $_SESSION['email'] in home.php page...why?

Comment: Look at my second sentence. You don't have a session_start(); in Check.php

Answer (score 1):

Add "name" in inputfield, please:

```
<form  method="post" name="login" id="form">
    Username <input type="email" name="txtUserName"  id ="txtUserName"  />
    Password <input type="password" name="txtPssword" id="txtPssword" />
<button type="submit" class="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OP's sending values through JS, that's not needed

Answer (score -2):

Now I know .
What are the mistake I do in my code.
And I modified my code.
Not there is no problem.

Modifications

1. Session_start(); included in all page as first line within php tag